# best-practices for displaying new view controllers ( iPhone )

Tags: iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

I need to display a couple of view controllers (eg, login screen, registration screen etc). What's the best way to bring each screen up?

Currently for each screen that I'd like to display, I call a different method in the app delegate like this:
Code:

```
- (void) registerScreen
{
 RegistrationViewController *reg = [[RegistrationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegistrationViewController" bundle:nil];
 [window addSubview:reg.view]; 
}
- (void) LoginScreen
{
 LoginViewController *log = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
 [window addSubview:log.view]; 
}
```

It works, but I cant imagine it being the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend reading the View Controller Programming Guide if you haven't: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

It sounds like presenting a view controller modally may be your best bet - but you'll probably want to wrap it in an UINavigationController first.

eg

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theControllerYouWantToPresent] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've often wondered if this is the best way myself, but when I'm not using IB's built-in stuff (like a NavigationController) I have a single method in the AppDelegate, `switchToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` that I pass...well, it's pretty self-explanatory I guess. This way there's only one place where it's done, and I can easily define transitions in that method once the app nears completion.

Also, don't forget to remove the previous views in your methods, otherwise you're liable to run out of memory. Something like this:

```
-(void) switchToViewController:(UIViewController *)c {
    if(c == currentController) return;

    [currentController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [window addSubview:c.view];
    [currentController release];
    currentController = [c retain];
}
```

Comment: Interesting,  So then how do you call this?  Do you Alloc and Init your new ViewController like normal, then pass it into this?

Comment: @Chris - I believe that at the time I wrote this that was what I did. I've also tried having the `AppDelegate` contain a list of its controllers, so it would go more like `[app switchToViewController:app.WhateverController]`. This has the advantage of easily preserving state. (My controllers were actually subclasses of `UIViewController` so they all contained references to the `AppDelegate`). I haven't done any iOS development in almost a year, though, so I'm not sure if I would still recommend this approach if I took a more critical look at it.